# Spacy tokenizer add exception for n't

Tags: spacy

I want to convert `n't` to `not` using this code:

```
doc = nlp(u"this. isn't ad-versere")
special_case = [{ORTH: u"not"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u"n't",specia_case)
print [text.orth_ for text in doc]
```

But I get the output as:

```
[u'this', u'.', u'is', u"n't", u'ad', u'-', u'versere']
```

`n't` is still `n't`

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Please try to edit your question - it's almost incomprehensible this way..

Answer (score 4):

The reason your logic doesn't work is because spaCy uses **non-destructive tokenization**. This means that it'll always keep a reference to the original input text, and you'll never lose any information.

The tokenizer exceptions and special cases let you define rules for how to split a string of text into a sequence of tokens – but they won't let you modify the original string. The `ORTH` values of the tokens plus whitespace always needs to match the original text. So the tokenizer can split `"isn't"` into `["is", "n't"]`, but not into `["is", "not"]`.

To define a "normalised" form of the string, spaCy uses the `NORM` attribute, available as `token.norm_`. You can see this in the source of the tokenizer exceptions [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/7128d65267240302b4537a7b30cff6cd6a7b0ff0/spacy/lang/en/tokenizer_exceptions.py#L195) – the norm of the token `"n't"` is `"not"`. The `NORM` attribute is also used as a feature in the model, to ensure that tokens with the same norm receive similar representations (even if one is more frequent in the training data than the other).

So if you're interested in the normalised form, you can simply use the `norm_` attribute instead:

```
>>> [t.norm_ for t in doc]
['this', '.', 'is', 'not', 'ad', '-', 'versere']
```